# How to read and write correctly unsigned __int8 array to binary file using filestream in C++

Tags: c++, filestream

I'm using generator to make random sequence of unsigned __int8'ers, and then writing them to file using ofstream.write() with this method;

```
void CDataGenerator::GenerateRandom(std::string outputFileName, int length, bool UseEntireRange, int max) {
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(outputFileName, std::ifstream::out | std::ifstream::binary);
    int count = 0;
    unsigned __int8* buf = new unsigned __int8[length];
    while (count < length-1) {
        int number = 0;
        if (UseEntireRange)
            number = rand();
        else {
            int rnd = rand();
            number = (int)((double)rnd / RAND_MAX * max);
        }
        int capacity = 0;
        if (number == 0)
            capacity = 1;
        else
            capacity = (int)(floor(log10(number)) + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
            if (count >= length - 2)
                break;
            buf[count] = ((unsigned __int8)(number / (int)pow(10, capacity - i - 1)));
            number %= (int)pow(10, capacity - i - 1);
            ++count;            
        }       
        ++count;
        buf[count] = BCD_SEPARATOR;
    }
    file.write((__int8*)&buf[0], length);
    delete[] buf;
    file.close();   
}
```

Where `const static unsigned __int8 BCD_SEPARATOR = 0xff;`

Then I try to read file with following method

```
unsigned __int8* CModel::GetRawData(std::string inputFileName, int &length) {
    std::ifstream file(inputFileName, std::ifstream::ate | std::ifstream::binary);
    length = file.tellg();
    file.close();
    file.open(inputFileName, std::ifstream::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    unsigned __int8* result = new unsigned __int8[length];
    file.read((__int8*)&result[0], length);
    file.close();
    return result;
}
```

Im my test generater creates sequence like this
**0x0 0xFF 0x5 0x6 0xFF 0x1 0x9 0xFF 0x8 0xFF**
but from reading stream I get
**0x0 0xCD 0x5 0x6 0xCD 0x1 0x9 0xCD 0x8 0xCD**
sequence.
It's obvously that all 0xff are replaced with 0xcd. Is it connected with (__int8*) casts and How do I solve it?

Comment: When you look at the file in a hex editor, has it been written with the right values?

Comment: Did you check that the reading or writing succeeded? That *opening* the file succeeded?

Comment: Also I suggest you use the standard fixed-width integer types like `int8_t`from [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) instead of the compiler-specific and non-portable `__int8`. I also recommend against using C-style casts in C++. Instead use something like `reinterpret_cast<char*>(result)`. None of these things should relate to your problem though.

Comment: @RichardCritten, in hex editor it has wrong values

Comment: You should probably use a debugger and step through the code writing to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With knowledge of the CRT debug heap that Visual Studio uses (I'm just assuming you're using Visual Studio), it's a good guess that the 0xCD value is from uninitialized heap memory. The question then becomes: Why are you seeing this in the output? To figure out why, you can simply step through your GenerateRandom function using your debugger/read the code.

From this it becomes apparent where the problem is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; ++i) {
    if (count >= length - 2)
        break;
    buf[count] = ((unsigned __int8)(number / (int)pow(10, capacity - i - 1)));
    number %= (int)pow(10, capacity - i - 1);
    ++count; //Increment count ONCE
}

++count; //Increment count a SECOND time
buf[count] = BCD_SEPARATOR;
```

The problem is that when the program leaves the for-loop shown here, count will already have been incremented once, so your "count" is already at your next uninitialized __int8 in the buffer. You then increment "count" once again before writing BCD_SEPARATOR to the "count" position in the buffer. This results in the program skipping the position where you actually want your BCD_SEPARATOR.

The next problem then becomes that, because you don't increment "count" between after you write the BCD_SEPARATOR to the buffer and the next time you enter the for-loop shown above, you immediately overwrite the BCD_SEPARATOR.

A solution to the problem could be to simply swap things around like this:

```
buf[count] = BCD_SEPARATOR;
++count;
```